# GTK track signals and events

Tags: python, events, gtk, signals

I am trying to track GTK signals and events. I have found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11373914/gobject-add-emission-hook-only-works-once) question, which does what I want. However, it seems to me that the emission hook will have to be declared for each signal of each kind of object. This will create a large list for used signals of each used element. Is there a better way to do this? Can I just track the signals and events and handle the arguments that are passed with it?

Comment: It's a bit hard to understand what your goal is ... Wanting to connect to all signals of all instances of an object type sounds like a design mistake.

Comment: I want to keep track of all signals that are emitted for logging purposes. If my application then breaks, I know how to reproduce the steps.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [GTK Inspector](https://wiki.gnome.org/Projects/GTK%2B/Inspector) to track all the signals that are emitted on an object. Pick the object in the inspector, go to the "Signals" tab, and click the Record button.